# Why did the Double Metaphone algorithm choose to substitute and merge consonants?

Tags: nlp, algorithms, text

Is there any literature describing the decisions behind why the mappings from input text characters to Metaphone hash consonants were made? Why did they choose to leave out vowels? Why did they merge consonants? Where can I find some of the reasoning behind some of the decisions made in the related phonetic algorithm(s)? I would like to see if it can be improved upon, but first it would be helpful to know some of the reasons why they made the decisions to cut and morph things the way they did.

In particular, I am imagining if you have the exact phonetic transcription of a word, then any deviation in the pronunciation will throw it off. So you want to perhaps make it more lenient, to handle slight changes in pronunciation. But the possibilities for this seem vast at first glance, so how did they choose what they did basically?

Getting rid of the vowels and making every vowel sound "A" seems to me the same as getting rid of every consonant and making each consonant "T", so "beautiful" becomes "TATATAT" and "emotion" becomes "ATATAT" haha, but that is taking it too far. So somehow you don't want to get rid of *that much* information, and somehow they chose just the right amount of stuff to toss out in the pronunciation, and just the right amount of stuff to keep, and I'm unsure how they ended up where they ended up. Am super curious to learn any insights in their thought process here.

From my [reading](https://github.com/words/double-metaphone/blob/main/index.js), they chose:

```
K: KGQ
S: SZ
X
J
T: TD
F: FV
N
L
H
M
P: PB
R
```